# wordpress author page visibility / 404

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress site where, when you open an author page on url

https://example.com/author/xxxxx/

will result in a 404, if the user is not accessing their own author page or when the user does not have the administrator role.

I would like my custom role - "inventory_worker", to also have the capability to see all other authors, but I cannot figure out, which capability I would have to give an inventory worker, so that he/she would not get a 404 for all other authors.

I have tried giving the inventory_worker role all the default user related capabilites that wordpress has, but it still did not work.

Comment: 1) check if your authors actually have some posts and 2) goto permalinks and see if that flushing pf the permalinks sorts it out.

Comment: Did not work, not the case. Need other ideas on debugging.

Comment: Sounds like you have a plugin that is controlling access to the pages?   If you know you have a plugin that is doing some kind of privacy or membership control, then deactivate that to test if it is causing the problem.  If that fixes, it check that plugin's settings.  If not then follow you need to check others.  https://webdesign.anmari.com/2932/debugging-a-possible-clash-between-plugins-andor-a-theme/.   Standard wp behaviour is the author archive is visible by all, only 404 on author archive IF no posts exist OR if all posts are private.